# How do I use Perl's XML::Twig to count multiple tags in XML?

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I am using [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/) to parse my input xml using Perl.
I need to extact a particular node in this XML and validate that node to see if it has multiple `<p>` tags and then count words in those P tags.
For example:

```
<XML> 
<name>
</name>
<address>
<p id="1">a b c d </p>
<p id="2">y y y </p>
</address>
</XML>
```

Output:

> Address has 2 paragraph tags with 7
>   words.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is it that people can't seem to get that XML is a *simple* standard? Attributes in XML *must* be quoted. Otherwise it's just a relatively controlled SGML. (XML::Twig will probably still work, but it's not XML.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $xfile = q(
<XML>  
<name> 
</name> 
<address> 
<p id="1">a b c d </p> 
<p id="2">y y y </p> 
</address> 
</XML> 
);

my $t = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => { 'address/p' => \&addr}
);
my $pcnt = 0;
my $wcnt = 0;
$t->parse($xfile);
print "Address has $pcnt paragraph tags with $wcnt words.\n";

sub addr {
    my ($twig, $add) = @_;
    my @words = split /\s+/, $add->text();
    $wcnt += scalar @words;
    $pcnt++;
}

__END__

Address has 2 paragraph tags with 7 words.
```

[XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/) has a dedicated website with documentation and a Tutorial to describe the handler technique used above.